# TikZ node label distance depends on length when using tikzstyle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

When I include `circle` in the `every node` style, the distance from the label to the node depends on the length of the label:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle]
\node at (0,0) [label={A},draw,fill] {};
\node at (2,2) [label={BBBBB},draw,fill] {};
\node at (5,5) [label={CCCCCCCCCC},draw,fill] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I delete the `tikzstyle` and add `circle` to the options for the individual nodes, this goes away:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [circle,label={A},draw,fill] {};
\node at (2,2) [circle,label={BBBBB},draw,fill] {};
\node at (4,4) [circle,label={CCCCCCCCCC},draw,fill] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's going on here and how can I avoid it, so I can keep `circle` in the node style?

Comment: Please complete your code to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which people can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Labels are also nodes. So TiKZ is setting each label in a circle. Since larger labels need larger circles, those labels are set further away from the labelled node. You can avoid this by explicitly specifying the usual rectangular shape for labels:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      every node/.append style={circle},
      every label/.append style={rectangle},
    ]
    \node at (0,0) [label={A},draw,fill] {};
    \node at (2,2) [label={BBBBB},draw,fill] {};
    \node at (5,5) [label={CCCCCCCCCC},draw,fill] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-circular labels]

Comment: Perfect -- thanks for the fix, and the explanation.