# How to force all labels to stay on the same horizontal line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, tikz-styles

[image: Note the relative node heights]

I'm trying to keep all of the labels at the same distance from the line. I've tried separating the nodes, but even if I remove all of the nodes except '1' and 'N+1', the three character label is higher. I've also tried:

- x-scale
- label distance
- label size = \tiny
- inner sep = 0pt
- outer sep = 0pt

But nothing seems to allow the three character labels to assume the same relative position to the line. Any advice? I've attached a quick-copy complete code as well as a picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw,shape=circle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]
        \draw[very thick](0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$1$](1){} -- (1,0);
        \draw[very thick](1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$2$](2){} -- (2,0);
        \draw[very thick](2,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw[very thick](4,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$i-1$](i-1){} -- (5,0);
        \draw[very thick](5,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$i$](i){} -- (6,0);
        \draw[very thick](6,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$i+1$](i+1){} -- (7,0);
        \draw[very thick](7,0) -- (9,0);
        \draw[dotted, very thick](9,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$N$](N){} -- (10,0)
         node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$N+1$](N+1){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Visualization of meshing elements and intervals including the complex $N+1$ node}
    \label{fig:nodeline}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TikZ node label distance depends on length when using tikzstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208017/tikz-node-label-distance-depends-on-length-when-using-tikzstyle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style `every node` define node style for labels too. When the label is wider, than the circle in your case is bigger and consequently the label virtually appear higher from line.

**Edit:** As *Ignasi* pointed in his comment below, also is necessary consider different text depth of labels. This are compensated below examples with:

```
every node/.append style = {text depth=0.2ex}
```

See, if the following solutions gives what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt, node contents={}}
every node/.append style = {text depth=0.2ex}
                        ]
\draw[very thick] (0,0) node (1)   [dot,label=$1$]  -- (1,0);
\draw[very thick] (1,0) node (2)   [dot,label=$2$]  -- (2,0);
\draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[very thick] (4,0) node (i-1) [dot,label=$i-1$] -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick] (5,0) node (i)   [dot,label=$i$]   -- (6,0);
\draw[very thick] (6,0) node (i+1) [dot,label=$i+1$] -- (7,0);
\draw[very thick] (7,0) -- (9,0);
\draw[dotted,very thick] (9,0)  node (N)   [dot,label=$N$] -- 
                         (10,0) node (N+1) [dot,label=$N+1$];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Visualization of meshing elements and intervals including the complex $N+1$ node}
    \label{fig:nodeline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Above code can be further simplified, for example with use of loop:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt}
every node/.append style = {text depth=0.2ex}
                        ]
\draw[very thick]           (0,0) -- (9,0);
\draw[dotted,very thick]    (9,0) -- (10,0);
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/1, 1/2, 4/i-1, 5/i, 6/i+1, 9/N, 10/N+1}
\node (\j) [dot,label=$\j$] at (\i,0) {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Visualization of meshing elements and intervals including the complex $N+1$ node}
    \label{fig:nodeline}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is the same.

[image]

Comment: I think that the lowest point of your labels is at same distance from the dot, but the final effect is that they are not vertically aligned because their `text depth` is not equal.

Comment: @Ignasi, thank you for pointed me to this. I will correct this (unexpected) behavior of label text ...